# php url executor with delay

Tags: php, sleep

Hi i am looking for a simple php script that can execute for exp 10 site url's from a list then sleep 1 minute and execute another 10 urls.. and like this again and again. Can someone give me a direction or can help me with a code?

Comment: In what way would you like to execute a URL?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: @ColaDeu I know what a URL is, what exactly do you want the code to do with it?

Comment: I have a list with urls and I need to access them regularly. I need an script that cand do this job and access my sites 1 after 1 with sleep between each access

Comment: lets fake traffic for ... some reason

Comment: thordarson just accessing the url's one after one

Comment: accessing? doing something with retuned data or just faking a visit?

Comment: Use curl/file_get_contents with sleep :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not very clear on this one, but the simplest way of simply requesting a URL is using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents). You're also looking for a loop to loop through an array of URLs. Pick your favorite for this one, I'll use [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Finally you need the [sleep](http://php.net/sleep) function.

**Untested code:**

```
$urls = array(
    'http://google.com',
    'http://yahoo.com',
    'http://bing.com');

foreach($urls as $url)
{
    //Make a request.
    $url_content = file_get_contents($url);

    /*
     * Do something with the content here.
     */

    //Wait a few moments.
    sleep(60); // Seconds.
}
```

For more flexibility you need to look into [curl](http://php.net/curl) which supports, among other things, POST requests and messing with headers.

Comment: I get syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 12

Comment: Now, I did state it was untested, but that's really not a hard error to solve. It's simply a missing semicolon on line 12. Try going through some tutorials and come back when you have a problem.

Comment: and i need for this script.. first it takes google,yahoo,bing , sleep 1 min and after, it takes amazon, etc etc, not the same sites

Comment: This isn't a script requesting site. [Write some code on your own](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and come back when you have a real problem. I just gave you the basics.

Comment: Sorry thordarson. But this is not good for me.